# createjs mask doesn't work (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'props' of null)

Tags: mask, createjs

i have this error when i run this code
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'props' of null
anyone can help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<script src="https://code.createjs.com/createjs-2014.12.12.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>


<script>


var stage = new createjs.Stage("canvas");
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", tick);

var ui = new Image();
ui.onload = drawShape();
ui.src = "A09.png";
```

// Redraw the shape each tick.
    function drawShape() {
   //Mask
    var shape = new createjs.Shape();
    shape.graphics = new createjs.Graphics()
    .beginStroke("rgba(255,255,255,1)")
    .beginBitmapFill(ui).drawCircle(35, 25, 20).endStroke();

```
var image = new createjs.Bitmap(ui);
image.mask = shape;

stage.addChild(image);
console.log("draw");
}
function tick(event) {
stage.update();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Currently, you are setting the onload to `drawImage()`, which executes the function immediately, and returns null. Change it to `ui.onload = drawImage;` instead (no parentheses). This may not fix the issue, but will make it fire at the right time.